# Changing the action bar overflow icon to the dark version

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my application I am using my own theme based on the Theme.Holo.Light
However I have customised the actionBarStyle, setting the background drawable to a blue gradient to fit with my app's style.

However, with the Halo light theme, the action bar text is dark, & the default icons, such as the **Up Nav arrow** and the **menu icon** are dark, these don't go on my blue gradient.

As you can see from my XML below, I have managed to correct the title text colour but I can't find the attribute I need to override for the icons.

**How can I change tell the theme to effectively use the icons on the ActionBar from Theme.Halo
instead of those Theme.Halo.Light but making the rest of my application remain using Theme.Halo.Light**

*Here's my current XML*

```
<style name="MyLightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_gradient_light</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_white</item>
</style>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` as your base if you want to do this. It will take care of these details.

Comment: Thanks, this sorts the icons, it doesn't appear to affect the text on the actionbar, eg. the title is still dark. So it would seem my override is still necessary

Comment: Yeh, it works ok, it the base uses the dark actionbar but as soon as I override the actionBarStyle so I can set my blue gradient the text acts as if it were the light action bar

Comment: Also make sure that if you place any custom views into the action bar (either as action bar custom views, custom tab views, or action views) that you use the proper Context so that they are themed correctly. You can get a Context themed for the action bar by calling ActionBar#getThemedContext().